# Constructing a deformation neighborhood

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a finite simplicial complex imbedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I assume that the vertices are in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ in order to represent all in a computer). I would like to construct a neighborhood of $X$ that is a union of a finite number of $n$-dimensional cubes that deformation retracts to $X$. Intuitively, I would say that starting with a grid of small $n$-cubes with side-length $\frac{1}{m}$ for large $m$ and definining $X^{cub}$ to be the set of all cubes in this grid that have nonempty intersection with $X$ should do the thing. However, how to choose $m$? Is it always possible to do it like this? If yes, is it possible to choose $m$ and construct $X^{cub}$ "algorithmically"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is easier 1) to find a neighborhood of $X$ in the standard cubical grid with side $1/2^m$, for some $m$, that retracts (but not deformation retracts) onto $X$; 2) to find a neighborhood of $X$ that is a cubical complex (but not a subcomplex of the standard grid) and deformation retracts onto $X$. To get (1), use 4.30 and 4.31 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3249v4 . To get (2), use 4.3 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0346v2 , or alternatively (this is slightly less effective) use Misha's answer and apply the canonical subdivision to cut simplices into cubes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard result in algebraic topology: Star of a subcomplex $X\subset Y$ with respect to the second barycentric subdivision of $Y$ (called the *regular neighborhhood* of $X$ in $Y$) admits a deformation retraction to $X$. This is all completely algorithmic.

You can find a proof e.g., [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/pltop.pdf).

It is probably also in Hatcher, Rokhlin-Fuchs, Rourke-Sanderson, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Misha. You still need to represent X as a subcomplex of Y that is topologically a union of $n$-cubes. But that should be easy.

Comment: If I got it right, in this way I can construct a regular neighborhood N(X,Y) of Y that is a combinatorial manifold. However, how to construct a neighborhood $\Omega$ of $N(X,Y)$ that consists of cubes (products of intervals) s.t. $\cup\Omega$ deformation retracts to $N(X,Y)$?